# What is the difference between subscription.unsubscribe() and subscription.remove()?

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, subscription

I am using Angular 5 and have subscribed an observable using the `subscribe()` method. I want to know if only calling the `unsubscribe()` method on the subscription will be sufficient to cleanup everything, or should I also call `remove()` method?

code snippet:

`

```
// somewhere in a method
this.s1 = someObservable.subscribe((value) => {
     //somecode
 });
// in ngOnDestroy
this.s1.unsubscribe(); // should I also call .remove()
```

`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.remove` remove the subscription from an internal list, but it does **not** unsubscribe.

`.unsubscribe` clean up everything, do the unsubscribe and remove the observer from the internal list. (There was a bug (fixed) that didn't remove the observer from the list)

`.takeWhile` keep alive the subscription whilst a certain situation continues to be `false`

example:

```
this.service.method()
.subscribe(res => {
  //logic
});
```

this will never unsubscribe.

```
this.service.method()
    takeWhile(() => this.isAlive) // <-- custom variable setted to true
    .subscribe(res => {
      //logic
    });

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.isAlive = false;
}
```

Automatic unsubscribe when the component is going to be destroyed.

```
   this.s1 = someObservable.subscribe((value) => {
        //somecode
    });

public yourMethod(){
    this.s1.unsubscribe();
}
```

this subscription will exists and be "alive" until `yourFunction` is not called.

--

I personally like to use the rxjs operator `takeWhile` to keep the code clean. In a very big project or single component having multiple subscription it's confusing having (IE) 30 `variables: Subscription`. So If you are asking when to use the `takeWhile` operator my answer is: (Taking as example one subscription) -> If you are sure that the `unsubscribe` needs to be done when the component is destroyed, use takeWhile. If you need to unsubscribe in a certain scenario where the component is still "alive", use the second example I wrote.

Hope to have clarified the argument.